# MS Access Forms: Control Default Values and DLookup

Tags: forms, ms-access, controls, default-value

I've tried searching on here for my answer but have had no luck.  I've tried many things to get this to work but haven't been successful so I thought I would post my question.  I may repeat myself several times but I'm trying to be as specific/detailed as I can.

I have a form which has an append query to transfer all fields on the form into a table.  On this form, I have an invisible control (textbox) which pulls the users Windows login ID and uses that as its default value.  I have another field (textbox) for the user's full name.

I have ran a query to pull employee data from my tables to have the employee ID (same as their Window's login ID, first name, and last name.  I have also ran an expression to concatenate the two name fields into one to show their full name.

What I've been trying to do is have it so that when someone opens up the form, their full name is already pre-loaded.  As I stated above, this is pre-loaded based on a comparison of their Window's login ID with their employee ID that we have on record as they're the same.  It's essentially Excel's version of vlookup() that I'm trying to do.  I've tried dlookup() but was unsuccessful.

Does anyone know how to make the default value of the employee name control on the form to be determined by employee ID control which has its default value based on the user's Window login ID?

**Example:** Let's say that I have an employee called Fred Flintstone.  In the database there's a table with fields for his first name and last name.  There's also a field for his employee ID which is A111111.

When opening up the form, there's an invisible textbox control which has its default value derived from the Windows login ID that the employee used to sign onto the computer with.  This Windows login ID happens to be A111111 which is the same as the employee's employee ID.

A query was created that has fields for the employee ID, First Name, Last Name, and an expression to concatenate the two name fields.  So the first row would be: | A111111 | Fred | Flintstone | Fred Flintstone |.  I don't know how to make tables on here yet so bear with me.

Going back to the form, there's a field for Employee Name.  How would I get it to show Fred Flintstone as the default value upon opening the form?

*Note:* The employee name field will eventually be locked so that it cannot be changed by the employee.  I don't know if that would have any impact but I thought that I would mention it.

Comment: can you post the code you currently are using? What is the error you are getting now? or what is happening that you are not expecting?  If you do this thru VBA, there really is no need for your hidden text box.

Answer (score 0):

In the onload event of your form (really rough code, will require some tweaking..):

```vb
dim db as dao.database
Dim rs as dao.recordset
Dim username as string 
dim SQL as string

username = Environ("USERNAME") 'There are better ways to get username, but this is just a quick example.

SQL = "SELECT * FROM Your_Query WHERE username = '" & username & "'"
set db = currentdb
set rs = db.openrecordset(SQL,dbopensnapshot)
if rs.recordcount > 0
  rs.movefirst
  me.UserNameField = rs!username
else
  msg "User Not Found"
End If

set rs = nothing
set db = nothing
```